# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status, undefined reference

Tags: arrays, c, compiler-errors

**Relatively new to programming here. I'm stumped here trying to figure out how to get this code to compile, but keep getting this error:**

I don't necessarily think it has anything to do with functions insert_array_ascend, get_value, read_value, or is_in_array, but to be fair you never really know.

```
/tmp/ccB0YyFX.o: In function `main':
lab.c:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `print_array'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

- 

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void insert_array_ascend(int array[], int n_count);
void print_array(int array[], int size);
int get_value(char *prompt);
int read_file(int array[], char *fname);
int is_in_array(int array[], int size, int input);



int main(){

    int primary[100];
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    char choice;

    count += read_file(primary, "input_numbers.txt");
    do{
            int user_value = get_value("Enter a value to test: ");
            int result = is_in_array(primary, count, user_value);
            primary[count] = user_value;

            insert_array_ascend(primary, count);
            count++;

            print_array(primary, count);
            if (result == 1){
                    printf("TRUE\n");
            }
            else{
                    printf("FALSE\n");
            }
            printf("Would you like to run again? [y/n]: ");
            scanf("%c", &choice);
    } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int read_file(int array[], char *fname){

    int position = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "r");
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[position]) != EOF){
            insert_array_ascend(array, position);
            position++;
    }
return position;
}

void insert_array_ascend(int array[], int size){

    int i, key, j;
    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++){

            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && array[j -1] > array[j]){
                    key = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j - 1];
                    array[j - 1] = key;
                    j--;
                    }
            }
    }

int is_in_array(int array[], int size, int input){

    int l = 0;
    int h = size - 1;
    while (l <= h){

            int checker = (l + h) / 2;
            if (array[checker] == input){
                    return 1;
                    }
            else if (input < array[checker]){
                    h = checker - 1;
                    }
            else{
                    l = checker + 1;
                    }
            }
    }


int get_value(char *prompt){

    int amount;

    printf("%s", prompt);
    scanf("%d", &amount);

    printf("\n Echo printing, read in the number = %d\n\n", amount);

    return amount;
}
```

What should I do in order to make this run correctly? Somewhat of a rookie so please help with laymans terminology. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You did not write the function `print_array` so the compiler cannot find it.

You need to write it.

```
void print_array(int array[], int size);
```

Only informs the compiler that this function is somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The error means "Function `main` calls a function called `print_array`, but the code for `print_array` couldn't be found anywhere".

Do you have any other `.c` files that contain the implementation/code for `print_array`? Because in the code you posted there isn't any such implementation.

If you had an implementation for `print_array`, it would be like this:

```cpp
void print_array(int array[], int size) {
    // The implementation/code of print_array goes here.
}
```

To solve it, either remove `print_array(primary, count);` within `main`, or, if you need it, then add the implementation like in the lines I wrote above. The error will then go away.